# Suggested way for common fragment listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

For Fragment-Activity communication, [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) is the suggested way of doing it, by using a listener.

In my case I have two fragments and a button at each and I would like them to do the exact same thing when pressed.

Should I create a separate listener class that the Activity implements and then instantiate a listener in each fragment or there is a better design that I am not aware of?

EDIT

I am sorry, I probably didn't communicate that properly. I am not looking for communication between fragments. I have a Fragment A with a buttonA and a Fragment B with a buttonB. When I click on buttonA, there is a listener in my Activity and method `doSomething()` is called. Now I want buttonB calling `doSomething()` too. Should I A) create a second listener and have the activity implement that too, B) create one separate listener class and use this one for both or C) a better choice ??

Answer (score 0):

For communication between fragment to frament or activity to fragment communication via events. There are few alternatives are there e.g. [this](https://github.com/square/otto) otto eventbus I know. and the tutorial about this can be found [Here](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/48752686831/playing-around-with-otto-on-android) or just google it.

Answer (score 0):

As from the documentation :

> Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

So you best follow the pattern explained in the article and communicate thru the activity on which the fragments are attached.
When a listener is called from fragment A then get the fragment B from the fragmentManger

```
 YourFragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b); 
 fragment.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this pattern and it works well for me:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    FragmentListener mCallback;

    public interface FragmentListener {
        public void onAction1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof FragmentListener) {
            mCallback = (FragmentListener) activity;
        }
    }

    public void onAction2() {
        // do your stuff...
    }
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    FragmentListener mCallback;

    public interface FragmentListener {
        public void onAction2();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof FragmentListener) {
            mCallback = (FragmentListener) activity;
        }
    }

    public void onAction1() {
        // do your stuff...
    }
}

public class MainActivity implements Fragment1.FragmentListener, Fragment2.FragmentListener {
    private Fragment1 fragment1;
    private Fragment2 fragment2;

    /**
     * Listening to events from first fragment and forwarding to second fragment
     */
    @Override
    public void onAction1() {
        fragment2.onAction1();
    }

    /**
     * Listening to events from second fragment and forwarding to first fragment
     */
    @Override
    public void onAction2() {
        fragment1.onAction2();
    }
}
```

The Activity listens to "events" from the fragments and if needed forward it to the other fragment(s).